# ASP.NET Core - Recommended custom authentication method

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

Reading the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.authenticationservicecollectionextensions.addauthentication

And meandering through all the extensions and method signatures in those docs, the options classes etc. it seems that the following (draft) code would be used to setup my own custom token authentication.

```
# Make an options class called MyTokenOptions derive from AuthenticationSchemeOptions.
# Make my own handler and scheme classes (omitted) and new them up.

var handler = new MyTokenHandler();
var tokenScheme = new MyAuthenticationScheme("MyTokenV1", "My Encrypted Token v1", handler);

# Now configure my classes with ASP.NET Core.

services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = tokenScheme;
        })
    .AddScheme<MyTokenOptions,MyTokenHandler>("MyTokenV1", myOptions =>
        {
            myOptions.AllowAnonymous = false;
        });
```

But it just seems simpler to make my own middleware component and read the token from the header, build my principal and just set `httpContext.User = myClaimsPrincipal` and return, or set a 401 and short-circuit the pipeline.

Do I need to do all that incredibly complicated stuff in the documentation?

Comment: Well of course you don't have to follow this steps if you want to integrate your custom authorization. But if you want to reuse or it even **other people** use it you should use that way as its easy to plugin in for 3rd party users or when you have many projects using that than to use a simple middleware

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that it's not just about authentication, but also *authorization*. Integrating with the built-in authentication system also buys you all the other auth goodies like policy-based auth, etc. If you roll your own, you'll have to roll it all the way down.

Comment: Also, FWIW, that's really doesn't seem all that complicated to me. You've just got a handful of lines of code - less if you condensed some of the extraneous blocks. Even the simplest possible middleware component would be at least as "complicated", if not more.

Comment: Don't roll your own mantra likely applies to custom authentication/authorization too.

Comment: Thanks peeps. A couple of us read the docs and thought it was typical of a design that must cater to every hypothetical situation. We only need to decrypt a token into a `ClaimsPrincipal` and then read it again from a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`. Do the simplest thing that works. If-when that no longer works we'll look at the "official" extensibility again.